# Get part of a value generated in an input by typeahead

Tags: angularjs

I have a form where I search with the name or code of municipalities all over Brazil. After doing this query, only display in the input the code of this search.

I need to get the "description" that generated in this input, to load it into another input.

```
<input name="municipiosServico" id="municipiosServico" type="text" required ng-model="contribuinte.codLocalPrestacaoServico"
                       typeahead="municipiosServico.id as municipiosServico.description+ ' - ' + municipiosServico.uf for municipiosServico in municipiosBr | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
                       class="form-control"/>
```

In the first input municipal municipiosServico.code display and in the second I need to display the municipiosServico.descricao.

I was trying to get by the municipalitiesServico.codigo, to go to the bank and return with the name of the municipality, but it would be very costly in terms of application performance.